# ajax send multiple value using jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

i have send single value in this script. but i try to multiple value send. using ajax.

**files.php**

```
   $(".search_button").click(function()
    {
var search_word = $("#search_box").val();
var dataString = 'search_word='+ search_word;
  if(search_word=='')
  {
  }
 else
  {
 $.ajax({
 type: "GET",
 url: "include/search.php",
  data: dataString,
  cache: false,
```

**search.php**

```
 if(isset($_POST['search_word'])){  

$serach_word = $_POST['search_word'];
$serach_word1 = $_POST['search_word1'];
    echo "$serach_word<br/>$serach_word1";

 }
```

i have some error so please solve this query.

Comment: This type of questions are already exists on SO.. Please put some efforts to search it first...

Answer (score 2):

You can Send multiple data with `data` attribute like

```
  data: { search_word:search_word ,search_word1:search_word1 }
```

And you also need to change the type to `POST`

```
 type: "post",
```

Comment: and what script write in search.php files.

Comment: The same code that you are wrote.As you need to `POST` the data ,you can get them using `POST` only right

Comment: @user3329459: `$serach_word = $_POST['search_word']; $serach_word1 = $_POST['search_word1'];`

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
$.ajax({
 type: "POST",
 url: "include/search.php",
  data: {'dataString': dataString , "value2" : value2,"value3":value3 },
  cache: false,
  success : function()
  {
  }
});
```

Use `type = "post"` as you are accessing value using `$_POST`

Answer (score 0):

in "data" you can add one or more parameter like this:

data : { 'paramA'  : valueA,'paramB'  : valueB,'paramC'  : valueC, ... }

;)

Answer (score 0):

-- set type to POST as you have used `$_POST`
 -- multilple data format like this:

```
 data: {'name': val , "name1" : val1,"name2":val2 }
```

Your jquery should be like this:

```
 $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "include/search.php",
      data: {'dataString': dataString , "val1" : value1,"val2":value2 },
      cache: false,
      success : function()
      {
       alert("success");
      }
    });
```

in your php you can get all values by the name like this:

```
$_REQUEST['dataString'];
$_REQUEST['val1'];
$_REQUEST['val2'];
```